# Sumar tiempo en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

estoy tratando de sumarle un tiempo determinado a otro.
Por ejemplo: tengo la hora: 23:00:00 (las 11) y quiero sumarle 2 horas (que me de 01:00:00) pero no lo logro.

Intenté con ADDTIME("23:00:00", "02:00:00") pero esto me retorna 25 ¿?

Como podría lograr ejecutar correctamente esta consulta?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Yo haría una conversión del valor `23:00:00` el cual, al fin y al cabo es una cadena. Luego usaría `INTERVAL` para sumar las dos horas y controlaría el formato de salida. Algo así: **`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('23:00:00', '%H:%i:%s'),INTERVAL 2 HOUR), '%H:%i:%s') hora;`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema puede resolverse de maneras distintas.

En mi opinión, la forma más segura sería:

- Convertir el valor `23:00:00` a fecha, dándole el formato `%H:%i:%s`, pues al fin y al cabo es sólo una cadena. De ese modo tienes el valor controlado adecuadamente y actuarías sobre un objeto `DATETIME`.
- Usar `INTERVAL`,  en vez usar *otra cadena*  para indicar las horas que quiero sumar.
- Controlar el formato de salida con `DATE_FORMAT`.

Aplicando lo dicho anteriormente tendremos entonces:

### Solución 1:

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('23:00:00', '%H:%i:%s'),INTERVAL 2 HOUR), '%H:%i:%s') hora;
```

**Salida:**

```
hora
01:00:00
```

La solución 1 hace uso de `DATE_ADD` en vez de `ADDTIME`.

---

### Solución 2

También se puede hacer con `ADDTIME`, sólo que en ese caso, no podrás usar `INTERVAL`, el cual, a mi juicio es más exacto que una hora *hardcoded*.

El resultado será el mismo:

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(ADDTIME(STR_TO_DATE('23:00:00', '%H:%i:%s'), '02:00:00'), '%H:%i:%s') hora ;
```

**Salida:**

```
hora
01:00:00
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias.